# Can not make a java.lang.reflect.Method constructor accessible when converting object to json with gson

Tags: java, android, gson

This is my first attempt trying to use GSON. And I'm getting this error.

```
Can not make a java.lang.reflect.Method constructor accessible
```

This is the code I use to create my json:

```
SoundEffects soundEffect = new SoundEffects("test", "test");
String json = new Gson().toJson(soundEffect);
```

This is the class soundeffects = new MediaRecorder();:

```
   public class SoundEffects /*implements Serializable*/ {
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
private String name;
private String output;

public SoundEffects(){

}

public SoundEffects(String output, String name) {
    this.output = output;
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getOutput() {
    return  output;
}
public void setOutput(String output) {
    this.output = output;
}
```

Placing an empty constructor in the class didn't help and the error still occurs.

Comment: 100% MediaRecorder class is the issue.

Comment: Test it, remove MediaRecorder.

Comment: Ok that solved the error.

Comment: But how should I implement the MediaRecorder class then?

Comment: Sorry I was doing something.

Comment: Personally, what I would do is decouple MediaRecorder. Try and see if you can do that.

Comment: What json text would you expect a `MediaRecorder` instance to serialize as? As an Android media class, it doesn't really seem to make sense that you'd want to convert it to json. If you want to skip it, you could just change that line to `private transient MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;`

Comment: Yup, that is what I what trying to say man.

Comment: It eventually turned we didn't need the MediaRecorder in our SoundEffect class. But anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialized by your custom adapter,

```
Gson getCustomGson(){
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(SoundEffects.class, new CustomDeserializer());
    return gsonBuilder.create();
}

class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<SoundEffects> {
    @Override
    public SoundEffects deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
           SoundEffects soundEffects = new SoundEffects();
           // do deserialize your object here
           .....
           // last, you can create the MediaRecorder and set to the object
           MedaiRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
           soundEffects.setMediaRecorder(mediaRecorder);
           return soundEffects;
    }
}
```